# How to access Context within a Class Component for react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to use my Context in a class component (MyEventsScreen), but whenever I do so, I get an error saying it is an invalid hooks call.

Here is **MyEventsScreen.js** (I've simplified it to be brief):

```
import { useAuthState } from "../contexts/authContext";

export default class MyEventsScreen extends Component {

 render() {
    return (
      <View>
          <Text></Text>
      </View>
}
```

I have my **authContext.js** here:

```
import React from "react";
import { authReducer } from "../reducers/authReducer";

const AuthStateContext = React.createContext();
const AuthDispatchContext = React.createContext();

function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(authReducer, {
    isLoading: true,
    isSignout: false,
    userToken: null,
    email: null,
    userID: null,
  });

  return (
    <AuthStateContext.Provider value={state}>
      <AuthDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </AuthDispatchContext.Provider>
    </AuthStateContext.Provider>
  );
}

function useAuthState() {
  const context = React.useContext(AuthStateContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useAuthState must be used within a AuthProvider");
  }
  return context;
}
function useAuthDispatch() {
  const context = React.useContext(AuthDispatchContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useAuthDispatch must be used within a AuthProvider");
  }
  return context;
}

export { AuthProvider, useAuthState, useAuthDispatch };
```

I have an **authReducer.js** here:

```
export const authReducer = (prevState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SIGN_IN":
      return {
        ...prevState,
        email: action.email,
        isSignout: false,
        userToken: action.token,
      };
    default:
      return prevState;
  }
};
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For class components you can use the `Consumer` provided by the `context` .

export your `AuthStateContext`

```
export const AuthStateContext = React.createContext();
```

In the class component you can use it as

```
import { useAuthState, AuthStateContext } from "../contexts/authContext";

export default class MyEventsScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AuthStateContext.Consumer>
        {(value) => { // read the context value here 
          return (
            <View>
              <Text></Text>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      </AuthStateContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}
```

Reference

[Context Consumer](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer)

Comment: Yup, this works perfectly. Out of curiosity, if I wanted to use the context in a ComponentWillMount, how would I do that? The only solution I can currently think of is to add a "refresh" button

Comment: Avoid using `ComponentWillMount` it is deprecated . Please use `ComponentDidMount` and also if you are creating this component from scratch i would suggest you to write it as functional component .